# Is there a function of Html.GetEnumSelectList<Enum>() that will set the value of the option to the value of said Enum?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

When using the built in Html.GetEnumSelectList() for the following Enum:

```
public enum Country {
        [Display(Name="United States")] US,
        [Display(Name="Canada")] CA
}
```

It generates the following html:

```
<select id="prefix" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">United States</option>
    <option value="1">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to have the value set to the value of the enum instead of the index?

I wrote an extension for what I needed, but it is so basic that it feels odd that the C# team missed it, so I'm curious if I did

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace HotelMaven.Extensions {
    public static class HtmlExtensions {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper html, TEnum selectedValue) where TEnum : struct {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                .Cast<TEnum>();
            return values.Select(eachValue => new SelectListItem {
                Text = eachValue.GetType().GetField(eachValue.ToString()).GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name,
                Value = eachValue.ToString(),
                Selected = eachValue.Equals(selectedValue)
            });
        }

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper html, bool isValueUsedForValue) where TEnum : struct {
            if (!isValueUsedForValue) return html.GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>();
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                .Cast<TEnum>();
            return values.Select(eachValue => new SelectListItem {
                Text = eachValue.GetType().GetField(eachValue.ToString()).GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name,
                Value = eachValue.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in what I'm looking for:

```
<select id="prefix" class="form-control">
<option selected="selected" value="US">United States</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Using:

```
<select asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Country>(Country.US)" id="country" class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Use attribute for enum and get and use it, for example this code get the DisplayAttribute value.

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum value)
        {
            if (value == null) return String.Empty;
            if (Cache.ContainsKey(value))
                return Cache[value];

            var enumType = value.GetType();
            var enumName = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
            var member = enumType.GetMember(enumName)[0];

            var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);

            var outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).ResourceType != null
                                ? ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).GetName()
                                : ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;

            Cache.Add(value, outString);

            return outString;
        }
```

I think u can define attribute for each enum value (by custom or available attribute like display attribute that u used) and store the value in this attribute and use it for value of option or any where.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm specifically looking for setting the value of a select list, not the display. Display is taken care of with the attribute that I show in the Enum.

Comment: I mean, put the value of the select list item in a attribute, like display.
u used display by attribute, then u can use Value by another attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the extenstion with a different name than `GetEnumSelectList` which is default

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumValueSelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) where TEnum : struct
    {
        return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
            .Select(x =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.GetType().GetField(x.ToString()).GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name,
                    Value = x.ToString()
                }), "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
<select  class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumValueSelectList<Country>()"></select>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Method overloading is viable here due to me extending the base functionality of the built in function.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by JavaScript if you want
For Example:

```
<select id="status" name="TicketStatus" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof (TicketSystem.Models.EnumStatus))" class="form-control" >
    <option value="-1">All</option>
</select>
<script>
    var st = document.getElementById('status');
    for (x of st.options) {
        x.value = x.innerText;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation as well, not just code.